# Turn grouping on or off

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, scheduler

I'm trying enable/disable grouping in KendoUI Scheduler at the users command. I'm using the MVC version of the program, and I've got a basic schedule up and working.

The code below will group my schedule horizontally using the ResourceID value. I would like to create a button that will turn this grouping on or off.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Web.Models.Calendar.CalendarActivity>()
        .Name("scheduler")
        .Date(today)
        .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 11, 01, 10, 00, 00))
        .EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 11, 29, 23, 00, 00))
        .Editable(false)
        .Height(600)
        .BindTo(Model)
        .Editable(true)
        .MinorTickCount(4)
        .Views(views =>
        {
            views.DayView();
            views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
            views.MonthView();
            views.AgendaView();        
        })
        .Group(g => g.Resources("ResourceID").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Horizontal))
        .Resources(resource =>
        {
            //specify the field from the model which contains the resource id
            resource.Add(m => m.ResourceID)
                .Title("Name")
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .DataColorField("Color")
                .BindTo(ViewBag.Resources);
        })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically change groups - add or remove them, you will need to re-initialize the whole Scheduler